# Align Card title with button on right side

Tags: lightning-web-components, css

I have a card with a header where I added a button.
The thing is that my Title and my button are not aligned

```
<header class="slds-media slds-media_center slds-has-flexi-truncate">
            <div class="slds-media__figure">
              <span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-standard-account" title="account">
                <svg class="slds-icon slds-icon_small" aria-hidden="true">
                  <use xlink:href="/assets/icons/standard-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#account"></use>
                </svg>
                <span class="slds-assistive-text">Packages</span>
              </span>
            </div>
            <div slot="header" class="slds-media__body slds-clearfix">
              <h2 class="slds-card__header-title">
                <a href="#" class="slds-card__header-link" title="Accounts">
                  <span>Packages</span>                  
                </a>
              </h2>
              <lightning-button  variant="brand" label="Create new Package"   title="Looks like a link" onclick={handleClick} class="slds-var-m-left_x-small slds-float_right"></lightning-button>
            </div>
          </header>
```

I tried everything with different results but without one that align the title verticaly while putting my button on the right
and it looks like this ..

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this out

```
<template>
    <div class="slds-card__header slds-grid">
        <header class="slds-media slds-media_center slds-has-flexi-truncate">
            <div class="slds-media__figure">
                <span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-standard-account" title="account">
          <svg class="slds-icon slds-icon_small" aria-hidden="true">
            <use xlink:href="/assets/icons/standard-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#account"></use>
          </svg>
          <span class="slds-assistive-text">account</span>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-media__body">
                <h2 class="slds-card__header-title">
                    <a href="#" class="slds-card__header-link slds-truncate" title="Accounts">
                        <span>Package</span>
                    </a>
                </h2>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-no-flex">
                <button class="slds-button slds-button_brand">Create new Package</button>
            </div>
        </header>
    </div>
</template>
```

FR : [DEMO](https://studio.webcomponents.dev/edit/uEtWpZZtvCbQ6QfI5NXl/src/app.html?p=stories)

Comment: Thx yo working as a charm